# android Ksoap 3.4.0 download file from NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123) fail

Tags: android, soap, nusoap, ksoap

There is a problem in `NuSOAP` http header `Content-Length`, causing `ksoap` parsing error

case 1.

> X-SOAP-Server: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
>   Content-Length: 3410

the http content length is 3410, match http body length and ksoap works fine

case 2.

> X-SOAP-Server: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
>   Content-Length: 15225

but the real http body length is 15228 shown in wireshark

`ksoap-3.4.0` parsing data depend on http header content-length,
the envelope end tag lost then xml parsing error.

**update**

the end of content

in wireshark

```
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

in android http connection inputstream

```
</SOAP-ENV:Envelo
```

it cause xml parsing error, can't find end tag

the root cause is nusoap content-length not match

Answer (score 0):

refer :https://forums.adobe.com/thread/725704?tstart=0

server response contain utf-8 BOM header cause this issue.

remove the header in http body
then content-length will match body length